# Bimodal distribution from uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a problem where I would like to generate a bimodal distribution from a given uniform distribution between different ranges of say, for example, (-1.0, +1.0), (-0.18, +0.18), (-0.12, +0.12) and (-0.15, +0.15). The example distributions can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgnkR.jpg).

So the problem is that you are sort of 'carving out' the bimodal distribution from the given uniform distribution. Again, I don't want to generate a standalone bimodal distribution! From a given uniform distribution, the bimodal distribution is to be 'carved out'.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: The distributions (other than having different ranges) appear to look very much like beta distributions.  And for any probability distribution (bimodal or not) one can generate samples from uniform distributions.  One just takes the inverse of the cumulative distribution function (although that might very well require an iterative procedure).

Comment: @JimB Can you provide some references which I can use?